# ActionBar complains about ActionSeparator already having a parent

Tags: kivy

When using `NavigationToolbar2Kivy` from garden.matplotlib in a deeply nested widget (it's why I could not setup a simple working example showing the problem), I am thrown the following exception:

```
WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionSeparator object at 0x147956fa0>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionOverflow object at 0x1478e44b0>
```

I could fix it by introducing the following changes in actionbar.py:

1. In `ActionView._layout_random()`, replace `super_add(child, group_index)` by:

   ```
       if child.parent:
           child.parent.remove_widget(child)
       super_add(child, group_index)
   ```

   `over_add(child)` by:

   ```
       if child.parent:
           child.parent.remove_widget(child)
       over_add(child)
   ```

   and `super_add(child)` by:

   ```
       if child.parent:
           child.parent.remove_widget(child)
       super_add(child)
   ```
2. In `ActionView._layout_all()`, replace `super_add(child)` by:

   ```
       if child.parent:
           child.parent.remove_widget(child)
       super_add(child)
   ```

I think that the problem comes from `ActionView.remove_widget()` and the complicated interactions between `_list_action_item`, `_list_action_group` and `hidden_items`, that I could not sort out.

As these changes are most probably harmless, I suggest these changes are included to improve `ActionBar` robustness.

Comment: That exception is being thrown the `Widget` class `add_widget()` method, way down the inheritance tree. It is telling you that the `ActionSeparator` is already being used in a `ActionOverflow`. All your proposed fixes will result in an `ActionOverflow` missing an `ActionSeparator` somewhere. I suggest catching that exception and following that stacktrace to see where `add_widget()` is being called, and continue investigating from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionOverflow` widget is not supposed to contain any `ActionSeparator`, as shown by its overloaded `add_widget` method.

But in `ActionView._layout_random()` (in the very last lines), items in `hidden_items` are added to `overflow_group` (which is an `ActionOverflow` widget) using the inherited `add_widget` method, not the overloaded one.

So, in `ActionView._layout_random()`, it is necessary to prevent `overflow_group` to receive any `ActionSeparator`, so it is necessary to replace:

```
over_add(child)
```

by:

```
if not isinstance(child, ActionSeparator):
    over_add(child)
```

This identifies and fixes the problem.